# Ability to specify unique parameters in an Amazon CloudWatch Events rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, rules

Is it possible to have parameters to AWS::Events::Rule ? Lets you have different scheduled rules that runs the same code but you want a parameter as input so that you can differentiate which rule that was triggered?

```
  ScheduledRule1:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Scheduled Rule
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Id: "MyJob"
          Arn: !GetAtt MyJob.Arn

  ScheduledRule2:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Scheduled Rule
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(60 minutes)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Id: "MyJob"
          Arn: !GetAtt MyJob.Arn
```

Comment: Why not use the rule ARN to differentiate? Why do you need an extra parameter?

Comment: I think in my case the ARN would be the same since they would both reference the same lamba arn. See if I can make an example to my question

Comment: No, I mean `ScheduledRule1` and `ScheduledRule2` are two different rules with different ARNs. So you can use the rule ARN in the event passed to your lambda function to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When specifying a target, you can provide a constant to help identify which rule triggered the AWS Lambda function.

Here it is in the Amazon CloudWatch Events console:

[image: CloudWatch Events]

In CloudFormation, this would be set via the `Input` parameter in the `Target` section.

Comment: When I do this using a java POJO I get:

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.PocRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('
{
    "input": "myinput"
}

Does someone know what the should be the difference between how you do this for a rule and how you normally do it with input to e.g a lambda

Comment: It's probably worth creating a new question so that you can show your code, rather than asking a comment.